# Not able to align concentric inner circle inside my outer div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sort of circle and trying to embed a inner circle but the inner circle is not positioning as required in the image.

[image]

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```

How can I position my inner circle as required without writing any Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions would be to use absolute positioning:

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: relative;
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following works:

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding: 10px;
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```

I've removed the margin and added a padding to the `.outer-circle`. That's gotta be the easiest way for now. Basically you make height the same on both circles, adding the padding to the outer-circle creates the gap between the two, the bigger the larger it will get.

Answer (score 1):

Additional info:
`margin`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)
`position`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.inner-circle {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use transform:translate

```css
.outer-circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(0px,50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```